# WiFi stop working after few days

Tags: wi-fi

I have problem with WiFi on Android 4.4.2. (phone ZTE Geek 2)
After few days of working  WiFi stopped work and WiFi connetion has an error: “Saved, secured with WPA /WPA2”
Router reset, change configuration phone restart didnt work

I made hard reset of conifiguration of phone and it worked for few days (about 5 days) But it stopped work again. And now only that hard reset helps to make WiFi work again

Tested with 3 different routers. 
Another phone work. This phone work only few days after reset.

Comment: I think it might be a bug in your OS. Are you using a custom ROM?
There are some apps called "wifi fixer" or "wifi connection fixer" and similar. Take a look at them. They perform magic to fix your wifi connection. The wifi connection fixer helped me in the past but that was for a different problem.

Comment: I used WiFi Fixer and it was disconnection every time phone was attempting to establish connection.